# Autofill dates on selected rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I go about autofilling dates on selected rows, example shown below. I'd like to autofill weekdays in selected rows to keep the continuation in dates.

```
╔══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ Date ║ 09.09 ║ 10.09 ║ 11.09 ║ 12.09 ║ 13.09 ║
╠══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║      ║       ║       ║       ║       ║       ║
╠══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ Date ║ 16.09 ║ 17.09 ║ 18.09 ║ 19.09 ║ 20.09 ║
╠══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║      ║       ║       ║       ║       ║       ║
╠══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ Date ║ 24.09 ║ 25.09 ║ 26.09 ║ 27.09 ║ 28.09 ║
╠══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║      ║       ║       ║       ║       ║       ║
╚══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: You want it DD.MM numeric format?

Comment: Yea, plan is to use it on selected cells on certain rows. Example C4-G4 and then continues on C9-G9 etc

Comment: Macro creation: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/create-a-macro.html Short on minutes, but this is the way

Comment: Use simple formula based on the date value inserted manually in B1. I.e. C1=B1+1, D1=B1+2, ... B3=B1+7, ...

Comment: There are many calendar templates in Excel, maybe they will help.

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest VBA macro which is the best suitable to fix the issue:*

[image]

- From **Developer TAB** click **Design Mode** then  hit **Insert**
  and next, from **ActiveX Controls** select & draw **Command Button**.
- **Double Click** the **Command Button** to open VB editor and **Copy & Paste** code between `Private Sub and End Sub`.
- **Save** & return to the Sheet.

  ```
  Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim Sdaterng As Range
   Dim Edaterng As Range

     Set Sdaterng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select St.Range", Title:="Select Single Cell", Type:=8)

     Set Edaterng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Range to Auto Fill Date", Title:="Include Start Range", Type:=8)

  Sdaterng.Select
  Sdaterng = Date

  Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Edaterng, Type:=xlFillSeries

  End Sub
  ```

---

- Now Click **Command Button**.
- For first Input box select the *Start Cell*.
- Press **Ok** button.

[image]

- Then for next Input box select *range to fill date (including Start date)*.

[image]

- Finally finish with **Ok** button.

*You get  dates in selected Range.*

[image]

**N.B.**

- You can repeat above shown method for another Range.
- This method can create list of dates horizontally as well as vertically too.
- Adjust Start & Autofill Range as needed.